# How to add controls dynamically to ASP.NET form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls

I do not know how to add controls dynamically to the form using C# .net. Can anyone help me? I know this with vb.net but I need to know the syntax in C#.

Answer (score 6):

In the form, the following code can add a button dynamically:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Text = "dynamic button";
button1.Left = 10; button1.Top = 10;  //the button's location
this.Controls.Add(button1);
```

Comment: This is how I do it. You can also add your button to some other control than this, just in case.

Answer (score 5):

In Aspx

```
<%@ Reference Control = "WebUserControl1.ascx" %>
```

U can use the following in the Cs file to laod the control dynamically...

```
if (case)
else
{
WebUserControl1 uc = 
      (WebUserControl1) Page.LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx"); 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc); 


}
```

or try this

```
 Content.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("UserControls/InventoryNav.ascx"));
```

Can also have a look at:

http://aspalliance.com/565

http://samuelmueller.com/2008/12/dynamicloader-plugin-dynamically-loading-asp-net-user-controls-with-jquery

http://forums.asp.net/p/1222567/2826338.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Below is the code to add controls dynamically to ASP.NET form.

1. Initialize a label
2. Assign text to it.
3. Initialize a panel
4. Add the label object to the panel.

```
     Label lbl1 = new Label();
     lbl1.Text = "Your message here";
     Panel panel1= new Panel();
     panel1.Controls.Add(lbl1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code that can be called on some events like page load or onload or even some user action like onclick.

```
protected void add_button(Button btn)
{
   try
   {
        panel1.Controls.Add(btn); // Add the control to the container on a page
   }
   catch (Exception ee)
   {
         lblError.Text = ee.Message.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: @NishikaDas Please stop spamming that link at the end of your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the below sample

lets say forms name is frmMain.

```
Button btnSave = New Button();
frmMain.Controls.Add(btnSave)
```

Comment: Please add your code in a code snippet block, it's just easier to identify code sections when scanning for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally acceptable to add the controls to a panel, be it that the panel has been added to the page in the markup or programmatically.

See the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx) for the C# syntax