# How to pass a full asp.net control or HTML tags from server code in C# to a specific place in HTML design?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm not sure if this is even possible,
but I wonder if I can generate a full control that its tags are stored in a text property to HTML page.
let's say that I have an `<asp:Image ....... />` or `<div><i href=""/></div>` as a Text, and it is stored in a property named `X in .cs file`, and I want this X to be placed in a specific line in the Html page.

is that possible?

in .cs file let's say I have something like this

```
X = @"<asp:Image ID = ""Image111"" runat = ""server"" ImageUrl = ""img.jpg"" />";
```

and in the HTML file I want this:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    . 
    <!-- X comes here but as a real control -->
    .
    .
    .
</form>
```

I'm not sure if it is possible but I wish to find a way to do this, any way.

Thanks in advance, best regards.

Comment: WinForms? MVC? Razor Pages? Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: Server controls are a compile-time construct. That is, depending on your mode, when ASP.Net first loads a web site this is all evaluated once at startup or it's moved into a dll at compile time for deployment. Changing a page forces a recompile. However, there are **many other** ways to include runtime data like images in your pages.

Comment: Joel Coehoom, thanks for your reply, it seems satisfying to me, I thought it is impossible to pass a full control, but thought maybe there is a way to do that. thanks.

Comment: Jonathan Wood, thanks for your reply, it is ASP.net MVC

Answer (score 0):

I would change the way youre thinking about this.  Sounds like what you want to do is create a server control then pass some sort of parameter into that control which will then change the output accordingly.  If you were using razor you can also have helpers which would handle this sort of thing.

This might be of interest.

[Pass data from a ASP.NET page to ASCX user controls loaded dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201312/pass-data-from-a-asp-net-page-to-ascx-user-controls-loaded-dynamically)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Passing a value is not a problem, but I thought about passing a full control, but seems impossible according to my searches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612557/how-to-add-controls-dynamically-to-asp-net-form whilst this is not forms, there might be some useful info half way down using web controls