# How to loop through datatable and add textboxes/textareas that run at server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am currently trying to loop through a DataTable and add elements to a page when it loads depending on the data returned from the database. I currently have the business logic working for retrieving the data and inserting the divs/headers, but am not sure how to add asp textboxes that I can return data back to the server.

I want to try and replicate the usual logic for a textbox (or as close to it) like the following:

```
//ascx
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_Textbox1" MaxLength="50" Width="180"></asp:TextBox>

//ascx.cs
string text = txt_Textbox1.Text;
```

Here is what I have so far

```
id = "....."
div_contents.InnerHtml = GetContents(id);

protected static string GetBuildingCode(Guid ItemGUID)
{
   string content = string.Empty;
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   //Business Logic For Getting Data
   
   content += "<div>"
   foreach (DataRow dr in dt)
   {
      content += "<div>"
      content += "<h3>" + dr.Name + "</h3>"

      //Add Textbox or Textarea here

      content += "</div>"
   }
   content += "<div>"
   return content;
}
```

I have tried adding the textarea like the following:

```
content += "<br /><textarea ID=\"txt_" + dr.ItemGUID + "\" MaxLength=\"1000\" style=\"width:90%; height:150px\"></textarea><br />";
```

This works for rendering the textareas, however I can not figure a way to access the data.

Comment: Hum, for any repeating data, a gridview, listview would be a better choice, would it not? Not quite sure of the goal here?

Comment: Since the textareas you are adding aren't part of the control hierarchy, you'd need to grab their values from `Request.Form["name goes here"]` manually on postback. You'd also need to assign a unique name attribute for each element. Though, using a Repeater as John Wu's answer describes would be a more Web Formsy way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how server side controls work in ASP.NET:

**Step 1**. Your web application adds controls to the list of controls in the page.

**Step 2**. The ASP.NET pipeline renders the page, which iterates over all the controls and asks them to output HTML. Each control then outputs its HTML. The pipeline puts all this HTML together and sends it back to the client. This step happens automatically.

You are trying to add controls by manipulating the HTML that was output in step 2. That will have zero impact on the controls in step 1. So it won't work.

If you want to add controls to the page, there's two options I can give you:

1. Add their markup to a repeating item, such as a [repeater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.8.1) control. The repeater allows you to define a portion of the markup that repeats, you can put your controls there and the framework will automatically make enough copies of them.
2. You can add the controls yourself using c# code, e.g. by using `Controls.Add()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612557/how-to-add-controls-dynamically-to-asp-net-form) for an example.